# Installing refills gem gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I am trying to install a gem `refills` for my rails application.

This is what i get when i run `gem install refills -v '0.1.0'`

```
ERROR:  Error installing refills:
    invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /home/alfie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/cache/refills-0.1.0.gem
```

Comment: rubygems was probably interrupted when downloading the gem delete file and try again

Comment: Yes, that's what i did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gem Installation was interrupted. All i had to do was delete the file and start again.